# TimeSpan timeformat mismatch C#

Tags: c#, datetime, format, datetime-format, timespan

A line of code where im trying to create a timespan object which contains `"00:00:00.000"`.

My time format is `"HH:mm:ss.fff"`, took it from a code that works with this exact time format in another project I have.

But it gives a mismatch exception.

Chatgpt and other answers in stackoverflow suggested to use `CultureInfo` from `null` to  the example below, but it does exactly the same exception.

```
string timeFormat= "HH:mm:ss.fff";
TimeSpan timeZero = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:00:00.000", timeformat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timespan` parsing is *little* bit different than `DateTime` parsing.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings):

> **Important**
>
> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers don't include placeholder
> separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours,
> hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these
> symbols must be included in the custom format string as string
> literals. For example, `"dd\.hh\:mm"` defines a period (`.`) as the
> separator between days and hours, and a colon (`:`) as the separator
> between hours and minutes.

There is no custom `HH` specifier for `TimeSpan`, it should be [`hh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#hhSpecifier) instead. By the way `timeFormat` and `timeformat` are different variable names, in C#, these names are case sensitive, you need to fix that as well.

```
string timeFormat = @"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff";
TimeSpan timeZero = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:00:00.000", timeFormat, 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here a [`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/el7Ere).

Be aware of that there is a read-only field as [`TimeSpan.Zero`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.zero?view=net-7.0) which you can use as well.

As a side note, `CultureInfo` always matters on parsing or displaying operations. When you use `null` for `CultureInfo`, it always uses your [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-7.0) property. That's why your parsing operation *might* fail if your input string's time separator won't match your current culture's [`DateTimeFormatInfo.TimeSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator?view=net-7.0) property.